# ConTeXt: column breaks (reduce balancing penalty)

Tags: page-breaking, context, columns

I'm trying to prevent ugly breaks of the items inside a `\startcolumns...\stopcolumns` environment:

[image: ugly column breaks]

```
\setuppapersize[letter]

\setuplayout
    [ topspace=0.5in
    , height=10in
    , backspace=0.75in
    , width=7in
    ]

\setupcolumns[n=3,separator=rule,balance=yes,distance=0.5in]

\define\eachtestpar{\EveryPar{%
    %\clubpenalties  5 10000 10000 10000 100 0%
    %\widowpenalties 5 10000 10000 10000 100 0%
    \keeplinestogether{20}%
}}

\defineitemgroup[test]
    [inner=\eachtestpar]


\starttext

\startcolumns
\startitemize
\item One
\item Two
\item Three
\item Four
\item Five\blank[medium]

      Thus, I came to the conclusion that the designer of a new system must not only be the...

\item Six
\item Seven
\stopitemize
\stopcolumns

\blank[5*big]

\startcolumns
\startitemize
\item One
\item Two
\item Three
\item Four
\item Five\blank[medium]

      Thus, I came to the conclusion that the designer of a new system must not only be the...
      \startitemize
      \item One
      \item Two
      \item Three
      \stopitemize

\item Six
\item Seven
\stopitemize
\stopcolumns

\stoptext
```

I don't want to completely prevent breaks, but I do want my penalties to take precedence over column balancing. Unfortunately `\EveryPar` with `\clubpenalties`, `\widowpenalties` and `\keeplinestogether` does nothing but reduce the space between the paragraph and nested list (i.e. uglier).

Specifically: a break less than 5 lines or 5 nested items should not happen; instead the columns should be unbalanced.

Comment: You are aware that spaces before commas are not ignored in ConTeXt? `\setupwhatever[foo=bar ,hello=world]` is not the same as `\setupwhatever[foo=bar,hello=world]`.  You are lucky that things in `\setuplayout` is parsed as dimensions.

Comment: Ah that's why it sometimes works, sometimes doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, there is no need to wrap `itemize` in `columns`.  The `itemize` environment supports columns out of the box.

To rigidly keep the lines together you can wrap the item content into `\start...\stopitem` and pack it into a `\vtop`.

```
\setuppapersize[letter]

\setuplayout
    [topspace=0.5in,
     height=10in,
     backspace=0.75in,
     width=7in]

\unexpanded\long\def\vtopitem#1\stopitem{%
  \vtop{%
    \rightskip=\leftskip\relax
    \leftskip=0pt\relax
    #1%
  }%
  \stopitem
}

\starttext

\startitemize[columns][n=3,command=\vtopitem]
\startitem One \stopitem
\startitem Two \stopitem
\startitem Three \stopitem
\startitem Four \stopitem
\startitem Five\blank[medium]

      Thus, I came to the conclusion that the designer of a new system must not only be the...
\stopitem
\startitem Six \stopitem
\startitem Seven \stopitem
\stopitemize

\blank[5*big]

\startitemize[columns][n=3,command=\vtopitem]
\startitem One \stopitem
\startitem Two \stopitem
\startitem Three \stopitem
\startitem Four \stopitem
\startitem Five\blank[medium]

      Thus, I came to the conclusion that the designer of a new system must not only be the...
      \startitemize
      \item One
      \item Two
      \item Three
      \stopitemize
\stopitem
\startitem Six \stopitem
\startitem Seven \stopitem
\stopitemize

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: The main issue is it doesn't allow any breaking whatsoever, unlike '\clubpenalties`, `\widowpenalties`, etc. I guess the vertical rules would have to be added via MetaFun?

Comment: Why is it that penalties don't affect itemgroup paragraphs, via `\clubpenalties`, `\widowpenalties`, `\penalty`, `\keeplinestogether` etc? I can force individual items together with `inbetween=\penalty...` but that only works as an on/off switch. Either 0 or 10000, nothing else matters. Also took me a while to realize that itemgroups have default settings: `before` and `inbetween` are `\blank[big]`, so using them even with a no-op will change your formatting.

Comment: I even tried adding some vertical glue `after` the itemgroup to allow intermediate penalties to work, but no luck. It is also frustrating that additional top-level items automatically shrink top-level spacing but not nested item spacing. Which makes the list appear lopsided requiring you to change the nested `inbetween` spacing manually.

Comment: Anyway the point is that I don't want encase itemized paragraphs and nested itemizations in a vbox. I would rather apply standard widow/orphan penalties. While tinkering with `dorecurse` I've seen certain combinations push the *last three words* of a paragraph to the next column while the current one isn't completely full. Also, I can't live without vertical-rule column separators.

Comment: The best way to phrase the problem, I think, is to say the column balancing penalty is too high.