# ConTeXt version of TeX glue

Tags: spacing, context, glue

Say I have the following vertical glues such that the inner content switches from top-aligned to vertically-centered when it would overflow:

```
\starttext
\hrule
\vbox to 1in{
    \vskip 0.25in plus 0in minus 1fil
    \hrule
    % The height of this box is variable.
    \vbox to 0.9in{\hbox to 1in{}}
    \hrule
    \vskip 0.25in plus 1fil minus 1fil
}
\hrule
\stoptext
```

What is the ConTeXt version when applied to this:

```
\starttext
\setupTABLE[r][each]
    [height=1in,
     width=2in,
     align={middle,high},
     strut=no,
     frameoffset=0in,
     offset=0in]
\bTABLE
    \bTR \bTD
        % What goes here? Or is this an alignment setting (to setupTABLE)?
        a\\b\\c
    \eTD \eTR
\eTABLE
\stoptext
```

You can't simply place the TeX version into a ConTeXt table cell because of a top gap which I can't get rid of and which isn't a strut (per `\showstruts`).

```
\starttext
\setupTABLE[r][each]
    [height=1in,
     width=2in,
     align={middle,high},
     strut=no,
     frameoffset=0in,
     offset=0in]
\bTABLE
    \bTR \bTD
        \vskip 0.25in plus 0in minus 1fil
        \hrule
        \vbox to 0.9in{\hbox to 1in{}}
        \hrule
        \vskip 0.25in plus 1fil minus 1fil
    \eTD \eTR
\eTABLE
\stoptext
```

The gap becomes worse when placing a `\vskip ... \framed... \vskip` into a table cell. As if the gap was compounded by a top glue that won't contract.

Comment: “What's the apple version of oranges?”

Comment: You keep making up those [XY Problems](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-does-xy-problem-mean).  You have to ask better questions if you want answers.

Comment: Everything is about [improving this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/528202/174577). I want to apply this alignment to the table cells as well as integrate [Wolfgang Schuster's autofit font-sizing](https://www.mail-archive.com/ntg-context@ntg.nl/msg29024.html). And finally [fix the column break / balancing penalty](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/528354/174577).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Vertical alignment in frames

What you'tr trying to achieve isn't possible with the default alignment options, the only options are to push the content to the top, the bottom or center it.

To simplify the example all of the use `\framed` (to be correct it's `\startframed`) instead of a table environment but the results should be the same.

```
\startsetups[framealignment]
    \startframed[height=210pt,strut=no,offset=5pt,framecolor=red,align=#1]
        \blackrule[width=100pt,height=100pt,color=green]
    \stopframed
\stopsetups

\starttext

\startcombination[nx=3,style=mono]
  {\setupwithargument{framealignment}{low}} {align=low}
  {\setupwithargument{framealignment}{lohi}}{align=lohi}
  {\setupwithargument{framealignment}{high}}{align=high}
\stopcombination

\stoptext
```

[image]

## Fitting the frame content

A problem you mention in your case is that the content of a table cell can be larger than the cell itself, normally you would use one of the followinf options.

1. Make the size of the cell bigger to fit the whole content, this can be done by omiiting either the `width` or `height` value. The cell can now grow in one direction to provide enough space for the content.
2. Reduce the size of the font for the table (can be done with the `style` or `foregroundstyle` keys) or the whole document (can be done with `\setupbodyfont`).
3. Change the size of the cell content by rewriting text to make it shorter or scaling a graphic to a smaller size.

## Getting rid of the space at the top

When you add a vertical skip with `\vskip` at the top of the frame the gap is larger than expected. What gets added here is the `\lineskip` value which can be better seen in the middle frame but you can use then `\offinterlineskip` command to get rid of it.

```
\startbuffer[lineskip:yes]
    \startframed[height=200pt,strut=no,offset=0pt,framecolor=red,align=high]
        \vskip 0pt
        \blackrule[width=100pt,height=100pt,color=green]
    \stopframed
\stopbuffer

\startbuffer[lineskip:big]
    \startframed[height=200pt,strut=no,offset=0pt,framecolor=red,align=high]
        \lineskip 10pt
        \vskip 0pt
        \blackrule[width=100pt,height=100pt,color=green]
    \stopframed
\stopbuffer

\startbuffer[lineskip:nop]
    \startframed[height=200pt,strut=no,offset=0pt,framecolor=red,align=high]
        \offinterlineskip
        \vskip 0pt
        \blackrule[width=100pt,height=100pt,color=green]
    \stopframed
\stopbuffer

\starttext

\startcombination[nx=3,style=mono]
  {\getbuffer[lineskip:yes]}{lineskip=1pt}
  {\getbuffer[lineskip:big]}{lineskip=10pt}
  {\getbuffer[lineskip:nop]}{lineskip=0pt}
\stopcombination

\stoptext
```

[image]

## Adding custom skip values

This is a case where ConTeXt doesn't provide a user level command to replace the `\vskip` command (the `\vspace` command is the perfect candidate for this feature) and you have rely on low level settings.

What you can do is to hook the settings in the normal `setup` mechanism because the `top` and `bottom` keys can be used to apply the skips to the frame content.

```
\defineframed
  [BleedFrame]
  [    height=200pt,
        width=100pt,
        align=middle,
        strut=no,
   framecolor=red,
          top=\vskip 0pt plus 0pt minus 1 filll\relax\nointerlineskip,
       bottom=\vskip 0in plus 1filll minus 1filll\relax,
       offset=0in]

\startbuffer[content:dofit]
    \startframed[BleedFrame]
        \blackrule[width=50pt,height=100pt,color=green]
    \stopframed
\stopbuffer

\startbuffer[content:nofit]
    \startframed[BleedFrame]
        \blackrule[width=50pt,height=250pt,color=green]
    \stopframed
\stopbuffer

\starttext

\startcombination[nx=2]
  {\getbuffer[content:dofit]}{}
  {\getbuffer[content:nofit]}{}
\stopcombination

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: I just updated my question. I was referring to the ability of the vertical glue to switch from top-aligned to center-aligned if the inner box changes height.

Comment: One strange thing is that it only works with the `top=` and `bottom=` parameters. I specified a top skip of `\vskip 0.25in plus 0in minus 1fil` and a bottom skip of `\vskip 0.25in plus 1fil minus 1fil`. If I follow the answer's example in **Getting rid of the space at the top** by putting the skip inside the frame (`\startframed..\offinterlineskip..\vskip..\blackrule..\vskip..\stopframed`) then the gap remains. As if ConTeXt is ignoring the height while stacking boxes. I have to put everything in a `vbox to 1in`. Or it looks like a `vbox to 1.125in` even though the frame height is 1in. Why?

Comment: *Edit:* It works fine with tables (I had inherited an incorrect setup).